# Motorola 6800 I flag at reset

Tags: assembly, 6800

This might be an odd question on an old processor, but I have written an emulation of a Heathkit ET-3400A microcomputer trainer in Java.  I was adding the ability to trigger interrupts, and the Motorola 6800 datasheet indicates the I flag (interrupt mask) is set at reset.  The 6800 programmer's reference, however, has a passage that indicates it is cleared at reset.  Anybody know which one it is?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, Retrocomputing.SE is another place you could ask.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Retrocomputing, so I've posted there too.

Comment: I was searching the Programmer's Reference manual and found nothing about the reset state of the "I" bit. Only the data sheet says that it is set. Which chapter are you talking about?

Comment: The [Visual 6800](http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/expert-6800.html) seems to show it being set on start. It's not a definitive source, but I'd expect that they'd have it right, it's a fairly big detail.

Comment: @sparkydave: Can you please add a link to the Retrocomputing question here, and likewise add a link there to this question?  That's standard procedure when you crosspost between SE sites.  Otherwise someone may spend time writing an answer on one site, not knowing it is already answered on the other.

Comment: Hi Martin, in section 3.3.5 in the description of the WAI instruction, it says "if the interrupt mask bit is in the reset state (i=0)".  Maybe I'm misinterpreting reset as the system reset, perhaps they meant reset as in cleared?

Comment: @sparkydave You are misinterpreting that. Reset means cleared (set vs. reset), not the state at processor reset.

Comment: @sparkydave: The latter seems more likely.  It wouldn't really make sense to have interrupts enabled on system reset; what if one arrives before you've done enough initialization to be able to handle it?

Comment: Here's the retrocomputing link [url]https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16177/6800-i-flag-at-reset[/url]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because this is not an MC6800 specific question, but it is about all documents from the 1990s and earlier, I will answer here and not on retrocomputing.stackexchange.com:

> ... if the interrupt mask bit is in the **reset** state ...

Until the 1990s, the word "reset" typically meant what we would call "cleared" today.

In some contexts (for example "RS-Flip-Flops") the word "reset" still means "cleared" (and not: "initial state") today!

So the text in the Programmer's Manual actually means:

> ... if the interrupt mask bit is in the **cleared** state ...